# Can I spend Etihad Guest miles even if they're very few?

Tags: loyalty-programs, etihad

Some airlines like Qatar Airways make it extremely easy to spend the few miles I have:

1. Look for flight on **main** website
2. Log in
3. Select how many of the miles to use just before payment

This is easy and straightforward, see their UI, which lets me book a flight even with 1250 miles:

[image]

Singapore Airlines has a similarly-convenient UI on their main website:

[image]

However I found that some airlines have requirements that make use of sub-5000 miles difficult, for example:

- you must use a dedicated website to "redeem miles"
- you must have a very high *minimum amount of miles*
- they suggest you "buy miles" in order to reach the minimums

**So how does Etihad deal with it?** Is it as easy as with Qatar? I'm considering to start accruing miles with Etihad.

Comment: Just count in km and you'll have twice more.

Comment: I recall Etihad being similar in this regard.

Comment: It would be great if anyone with a Etihad Guest account could attempt to book a flight and take a screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell Etihad does *not* have an option to mix miles and cash.  That said, the exchange rate you get your points this way is typically terrible, it's much better value for money to redeem flights directly.  For comparison, on Singapore Airlines a mile is worth under 1 cent when paying for a flight, but up to 4/8 cents when redeeming business/first class.

But if you have small amounts of points left over, they do offer an extensive [Etihad Rewards](https://rewards.etihadguest.com/) catalogue that lets you buy all sorts of things or donate points to charities even in small quantities, eg [767 miles](https://rewards.etihadguest.com/catalog/product/view/id/478524/s/compensatemonthdrivingemissionsinastandardcar/category/23883/) to offset emissions equivalent to a month of driving.